# ADL with typedefs from another namespace

Tags: c++, typedef, argument-dependent-lookup

I have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace N
{
   typedef std::pair<int, double> MyPair;
   std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, MyPair const & mypair)
   {
      ///
   }
}

int main()
{
    N::MyPair pr;
    std::cout << pr;
}
```

This naturally doesn't work, because ADL won't find `operator<<` because `namespace N` is not associated with `MyPair` (unfortunately). Afaik one may not add to namespace std, so if I chose to define `operator <<` in std that would be kinda illegal. So... what to do in such situations? I don't want to explicitly qualify `operator <<`, nor do I wish to write `using namespace N`. So, questions are:

1. How to refactor the code?
2. Why wouldn't ADL associate namespaces of typedefs? Serious reasons? It would be nice, e.g. in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You could create your own type in namespace N, possibly inheriting from std::pair.  You could add "using namespace N;" inside main.  The former is more likely to be useful.
2. Because the type is defined in another namespace and cannot be defined in two.

Example:

```
namespace N { 
struct MyPair : std::pair<int, double> {
  MyPair(int first, double second) : std::pair<int, double>(first, second) {}
  // add defaults if desired: first=0, second=0.0
  // with defaults, you may want to make the ctor explicit or leave implicit

  // also, if desired and you don't use two defaults above:
  MyPair() : std::pair<int, double>(0, 0.0) {}

  // in 0x, you can "import" the base's ctors with a using declaration
};
}
```

If being used as a std::pair isn't important, you can drop the inheritance and rename the members.  In either case you can, of course, add additional methods, but if you keep the inheritance you can use "renaming methods":

```
int      & foo()       { return first; }
int const& foo() const { return first; }
double      & bar()       { return second; }
double const& bar() const { return second; }
```

Comment: @Armen: What seems artificial?

Comment: @Roger: Creating a new class just for ADL's sake

Comment: @Armen: Well, it's not. :) Think about it this way, what makes your MyPair type special?  It's special because you want special output formatting for it.  How do you differentiate MyPair from every other pair?  You create a special type for it.

Comment: And if MyPair isn't special, then it doesn't need its own output formatting, and you should either handle op<< for all std::pair types or for none.

Comment: @Armen: Remember that typedefs are aliases; similar to namespace aliases and references, in that way.

Comment: @Armen: I also have an [example of overloading op<< for various stdlib types](http://bitbucket.org/rdpate/kniht/src/889187d1db84/kniht/streamutil.hxx#cl-108), but I use a specific namespace so they can't collide and you explicitly have to request them.  When MyPair really isn't a special type, this is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @Roger: Yeah, I have seen it, you've advertised it quite a lot in SO, and I also, as you may remember, have stated that it is quite boostworthy :)

Comment: @Armen: I hope it's not seen as advertising, it's all MIT-style licensed and I really just want people to use the code rather than scratch their heads and reinvent broken wheels.  For the latter, so many people... hard to keep them straight at times. :)

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a reason why `typedef` names should not participate in ADL. Furthermore, it makes the following code implementation defined :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

namespace my {
class A {};
void for_each();
} // my

int main()
{
    std::vector<my::A> v;
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [...]);
}
```

- If `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a typedef for something which sits in the std namespace : `std::for_each` will be called
- If `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a typedef for `my::A *` : the compiler should complain that `my::for_each` doesn't take 3 arguments

Answer (score 2):

Your options are to:

- Define a new type which uses std::pair in its implementation, instead of using typedef
- Use a different name for your output function
- Explicitly qualify the function you want when you call it
- (Maybe) Specialize the function in namespace std (I'm not sure if `pair<int,double>` counts as a UDT)

This all stems from the main strength and weakness of typedefs: typedef names are just synonyms. It doesn't matter what namespace you put it in, the typedef name refers to the associated type, in whatever namespace that type is defined in. This is distinct from a typedef being a new type that is convertible to/from the associated type. Imagine this scenario:

```
class C{};
typedef C id_t;
void f(C);
int f(id_t); // error: structurally equivalent to `int f(C);`
```

This is invalid, because int and id_t aren't distinct types. This extends to ADL:

```
namespace A{
  class C{};
  void f(C);
  void g(C);
}

namespace B{
  typedef C id_t;
  int f(id_t); // structurally equivalent to `void f(C);`
}

B::id_t id; // completely equivalent to `A::C id;`
int n = f(id); // error: A::f doesn't return int
```

And here's a question for you: Do you believe that the following should fail to compile? If not, how should the name lookup be resolved:

```
B::id_t id;
g(id);
```

Comment: Well, yes, I believe it should not, ideally, fail to compile. The name lookup would proceed as follows: if the argument expression is an identifier which was declared with a typedefed-type then the associated namespaces to look for g must include the namespace in which the typedef was declares.. Something like that... But giving it some thought I am feeling it would be hideos and useless and problematic...

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by pulling the relevant symbol(s) into the namespace I want to use them from:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N
{
   typedef std::pair<int, double> MyPair;
   std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, MyPair const & mypair)
   {
      ///
   }
}

using N::operator <<; // now it should compile

int main()
{
    N::MyPair pr;
    std::cout << pr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a strong typedef:

```
#include<boost/strong_typedef.hpp>    
#include<iostream>

namespace N
{
// typedef std::pair<int, double> MyPair;
   typedef std::pair<int, double> pair_int_double; 
   BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(pair_int_double, MyPair);

   std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, MyPair const & mypair)
   {
      return o;
   }
}

int main(){
    N::MyPair pr;
    std::cout << pr;
}
```

(The extra typedef is still necessary to avoid the extra comma in the macro.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific data type which you want to output, you can always define your own class rather than use `std::pair`.

```
struct myPair
{
  int first;
  double second;
};
```

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: That would help because then ADL would find operator << in namespace N

Comment: You might as well inherit, especially if you're going to use the same member names. :) However, you can only add using declarations for ctors in 0x.

Comment: @Roger: By the way, does 0x allow adding to namespace std? This is a very annoying restriction

Comment: @Armen: As far as I know, you have the same restrictions as in 03: can only specialize when you include a UDT.  It's not so useful in 03 since you can't partially specialize functions, but I don't believe pair<int,double> counts as a UDT anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It **is** allowed to add specialization of template functions to `namespace::std` however since none of the types used in `MyPair` is user defined I'm not *sure* such a specialization is legal.

```
namespace std {
     template<>
     ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyPair& p) { }
}
```