# Why doesn't std::pair have iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

Why doesn't `std::pair` have iterators?

`std::pair` should provide `iterator` and `const_iterator` as well as `begin()` and `end()` -- just for their two members.

I think it would be useful because then we could pass them into templated functions that expect iterables, like `vector` or `set`.

Are there any downsides to this?

Comment: `std::pair<int, std::string>`. Iterators only work on homogeneous containers.

Comment: Although `std::pair` is sometimes used as a range, nothing about it requires or even encourages use as such -- so specializing for that wouldn't be too great. An early draft of C++11 actually had this at one point. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167598/why-was-pair-range-access-removed-from-c11

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to pass your objects to such templated functions then you should probably use `std::array<T, 2>` rather than `std::pair<T>`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One reason is that the two elements of a pair can be of different types. This doesn't fit with the iterator model.

The same goes for tuples, where having iterators would perhaps be even more appealing.

If you need an inexpensive *homogenous* container of a fixed length, you could use `std::array<T, n>`.

Comment: The std has std::pair<ForwardIt,ForwardIt> std::equal_range

Comment: @QuentinUK Your comment is not helpful for those of us who don't know what that does.

Comment: I would have put a longer explanation but it is not possible in the limited number of characters allowed in a comment. One could at least Google for further information.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `std::pair` is not to be a traditional container but rather to serve as a tuple that allows two potentially heterogeneous objects to be treated as a single one.

Additionally, because you have direct access to both parts of the pair, and because the types paired may not be the same, an iterator makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any particular downside other than that it only works for `pair<T,T>`, not `pair<T,U>`.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace itpair {
    template <typename T>
    struct pair_iterator : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T> {
        std::pair<T,T> *container;
        int idx;
        pair_iterator(std::pair<T,T> *container, int idx) : container(container), idx(idx) {}
        T &operator*() const {
            return idx ? container->second : container->first;
        }
        T *operator->() const {
            return &*this;
        }
        friend pair_iterator &operator++(pair_iterator &self) {
            self.idx += 1;
            return self;
        }
        friend pair_iterator operator++(pair_iterator &self, int) {
            pair_iterator result = self;
            ++self;
            return result;
        }
        friend bool operator==(const pair_iterator &self, const pair_iterator &other) {
            return self.container == other.container && self.idx == other.idx;
        }
        friend bool operator!=(const pair_iterator &self, const pair_iterator &other) {
            return !(self == other);
        }
    };

    template <typename T>
    pair_iterator<T> begin(std::pair<T,T> &p) {
        return pair_iterator<T>(&p, 0);
    }
    template <typename T>
    pair_iterator<T> end(std::pair<T,T> &p) {
        return pair_iterator<T>(&p, 2);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::pair<int,int> p = std::make_pair(1, 2);
    using namespace itpair;
    std::vector<int> v(begin(p), end(p));
    std::cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << "\n";
}
```

Of course you want a `const_iterator` too, and next you'll be wanting it to be random-access (which means more operators).

Like everyone says, though, that's not really what `pair` is for. It's just not a Container.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution. Not very "sexy", but it should work:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/optional.hpp>

namespace pair_iterator {

template <class A, class B, class Pair>
class PairIterator {
public:
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = std::common_type_t<A, B>;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = std::add_pointer_t<value_type>;
    using reference = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<value_type>;
    using const_reference = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<const value_type>;
private:
    boost::optional<Pair &> pair = {};
    difference_type index = 2;
public:
    PairIterator(
        const boost::optional<Pair &> &pair = {},
        difference_type index = 2
    ) : pair(pair), index(index) {}

    // Iterator

    PairIterator(PairIterator&&) = default;
    PairIterator(const PairIterator&) = default;
    PairIterator &operator =(PairIterator&&) = default;
    PairIterator &operator =(const PairIterator&) = default;
    ~PairIterator() = default;

    void swap(PairIterator &other) {
        std::swap(pair, other.pair);
        std::swap(index, other.index);
    }

    reference operator *() {
        return index == 0 ? pair->first : pair->second;
    }

    const_reference operator *() const {
        return index == 0 ? pair->first : pair->second;
    }

    PairIterator &operator ++() {
        ++index;
        return *this;
    }

    // InputIterator

    bool operator ==(const PairIterator &other) const {
        return index == other.index;
    }

    bool operator !=(const PairIterator &other) const {
        return index != other.index;
    }

    PairIterator operator ++(int) const {
        return { pair, index+1 };
    }

    // ForwardIterator

    // BidirectionalIterator

    PairIterator &operator --() {
        --index;
        return *this;
    }

    PairIterator operator --(int) const {
        return { pair, index-1 };
    }

    // RandomAccessIterator

    PairIterator &operator +=(difference_type n) {
        index += n;
        return *this;
    }

    PairIterator operator +(difference_type n) const {
        return { pair, index+n };
    }

    PairIterator &operator -=(difference_type n) {
        index -= n;
        return *this;
    }

    PairIterator operator -(difference_type n) const {
        return { pair, index-n };
    }

    difference_type operator -(const PairIterator &other) const {
        return index - other.index;
    }

    reference operator [](difference_type n) {
        return (index+n) == 0 ? pair->first : pair->second;
    }

    const_reference operator [](difference_type n) const {
        return (index+n) == 0 ? pair->first : pair->second;
    }

    bool operator <(const PairIterator &other) const {
        return index < other.index;
    }

    bool operator >(const PairIterator &other) const {
        return index > other.index;
    }

    bool operator <=(const PairIterator &other) const {
        return index <= other.index;
    }

    bool operator >=(const PairIterator &other) const {
        return index >= other.index;
    }
};

template <class A, class B>
auto begin(std::pair<A, B> &pair) ->
PairIterator<A, B, std::pair<A, B>> {
    return { pair, 0 };
}

template <class A, class B>
auto end(std::pair<A, B> &pair) ->
PairIterator<A, B, std::pair<A, B>> {
    return { pair, 2 };
}

template <class A, class B>
auto begin(const std::pair<A, B> &pair) ->
PairIterator<const A, const B, const std::pair<A, B>> {
    return { pair, 0 };
}

template <class A, class B>
auto end(const std::pair<A, B> &pair) ->
PairIterator<const A, const B, const std::pair<A, B>> {
    return { pair, 2 };
}

} // namespace pair_iterator

namespace std {

using pair_iterator::begin;
using pair_iterator::end;

} // namespace std
```