# Can range based for loop work over a range

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach

If I have range (pair of 2 iterators) is there a way to write "for each" loop for that uses range, not a raw array or container.

Something like this:

```
auto rng = std::equal_range(v.begin(),v.end(),1984);
for(const auto& elem: rng) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If you can use boost, boost has a range iterator.

Comment: yes I can, and I do :) <3 boost

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per [Why was pair range access removed from C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167598/why-was-pair-range-access-removed-from-c11?rq=1) you can use an adaptor e.g. the `as_range` at the accepted answer, [`boost::make_iterator_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html), or write your own:

```
template<typename It> struct range {
   It begin_, end_;
   It begin() const { return begin_; }
   It end() const { return end_; }
};
template<typename It> range<It> as_range(const std::pair<It, It> &p) {
   return {p.first, p.second};
}

auto rng = std::equal_range(v.begin(),v.end(),1984);
for(const auto& elem: as_range(rng))
    ...
```

The reason this isn't applicable in general is that per [Alastair Meredith's paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2977.pdf), of the algorithms,

- `mismatch` and `partition_copy` return a pair of iterators from different ranges;
- `minmax` returns a pair of objects that may not be iterators at all, and if they are there's no guarantee they form a range;
- `minmax_element` can return a range, but it can also return a reversed range (e.g. on a reverse-sorted range `minmax_element` will return `{prev(last), first}`;
- `equal_range` is guaranteed to return a range.

Comment: do you know what functions return invalid range? I mean in std, not user junk :P

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it will work like that out of the box as `equal_range` returns a pair of iterators while, the for cycle over range according to [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) are:

```
The begin_expr and end_expr are defined to be either:
If (__range) is an array, then (__range) and (__range + __bound), where __bound is the array bound
If (__range) is a class and has either a begin or end member (or both), then begin_expr is __range.begin() and end_expr is __range.end();
Otherwise, begin(__range) and end(__range), which are found based on argument-dependent lookup rules with std as an associated namespace.
```

I would say you may define `begin` and `end` functions that take the pair of iterators and return first and second one resepectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename I>
struct range_adapter {
    std::pair<I, I> p;

    range_adapter(const std::pair<I, I> &p) : p(p) {}

    I begin() const { return p.first; }
    I end() const { return p.second; }
};

template <typename I>
range_adapter<I> in_range(const std::pair<I, I> &p)
{
    return range_adapter<I>(p);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 };

    auto r = std::equal_range(data.begin(), data.end(), 2);

    for (const auto &elem : in_range(r))
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What `std::equal_range` returns is simply a std::pair. The standard doesn't cover any method to iterate over such things.

What you may want to read is Alexandrescu's ["Iterators must go"](http://www.slideshare.net/rawwell/iteratorsmustgo) presentation. [Here is the video](http://blip.tv/boostcon/boostcon-2009-keynote-2452140). An excellent read on a more elegant way to iterate containers using Ranges.

Ranges are implemented in his [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: ranges are implemented in boost and they are on their way to std, so anybody who wants to use them should use boost

Comment: I am aware of Boost.Range however I didn't take quite a good look at it, wasn't sure if they're the same as Alexandrescu's Ranges. Which is why I didn't suggest Boost.Range. Are you sure they're the same thing?

Comment: afaik no, but idk the difference, if iirc corectly boost/std ranges are just pairs of iters.... but i really dont know the details...