# Iterating over edges of a graph using range-based for

Tags: c++, graph, c++11, foreach, boost-graph

I have a representation of a graph as a `std::vector<std::unordered_set<unsigned>> neighbors`, that is, vertices are integers, and for each vertex we keep a set of its neighbors. Thus, to walk all edges, I would do something like

```
for (unsigned u = 0; u < neighbors.size(); ++u)
    for (unsigned v : neighbors[u])
        if (u <= v)
            std::cout << u << ' ' << v << std::endl;
```

Now, I would like to be able to get the same effect from

```
for (auto e: g.edges())
    std::cout << e.first << ' ' << e.second << std::endl;
```

where `g` is from a class encapsulating the `neighbors` vector.

However, everything I tried seems extremely complicated, the best version I can come up with has 50 lines, and it's hard to see that it is correct. Is there a simple way to do this?

Here's my ugly version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
typedef unsigned Vertex;
class Graph {
public:
    typedef std::unordered_set<Vertex> Neighbors;
    std::size_t numVertices() const { return neighbors_.size(); }
    Graph(std::size_t n = 0) : neighbors_(n) { }
    void addEdge(Vertex u, Vertex v) {
        neighbors_[u].insert(v);
        neighbors_[v].insert(u);
    }
    class EdgeIter {
        friend Graph;
    public:
        bool operator!=(const EdgeIter& other) { return u_ != other.u_; }
        void operator++() {
            do {
                ++it_;
                while (it_ == it_end_) {
                    u_++;
                    if (u_ >= neighbors_.size())
                        break;
                    it_     = neighbors_[u_].cbegin();
                    it_end_ = neighbors_[u_].cend();
                }
            } while (u_ < neighbors_.size() && *it_ < u_);
        }
        std::pair<Vertex, Vertex> operator*() { return {u_, *it_}; }
    private:
        EdgeIter(const std::vector<std::unordered_set<Vertex> >& neighbors, size_t u)
            : u_(u), neighbors_(neighbors) {
            if (u < neighbors_.size()) {
                it_     = neighbors_[u_].cbegin();
                it_end_ = neighbors_[u_].cend();
                while (it_ == it_end_) {
                    u_++;
                    if (u_ >= neighbors_.size())
                        break;
                    it_     = neighbors_[u_].cbegin();
                    it_end_ = neighbors_[u_].cend();
                }
            }
        }
        Vertex u_;
        const std::vector<std::unordered_set<Vertex> >& neighbors_;
        std::unordered_set<Vertex>::const_iterator it_, it_end_;
    };
    EdgeIter edgesBegin() const { return EdgeIter(neighbors_, 0); }
    EdgeIter edgesEnd()   const { return EdgeIter(neighbors_, neighbors_.size()); }
    class Edges {
    public:
        Edges(const Graph& g) : g_(g) { }
        EdgeIter begin() const { return g_.edgesBegin(); }
        EdgeIter end  () const { return g_.edgesEnd();   }
    private:
        const Graph& g_;
    };
    Edges edges() { return Edges(*this); }
    std::vector<Neighbors> neighbors_;
};
int main() {
    Graph g(5);
    g.addEdge(1, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.addEdge(1, 3);    
    for (unsigned u = 0; u < g.numVertices(); ++u)
        for (unsigned v : g.neighbors_[u])
            if (u <= v)
                std::cout << u << ' ' << v << std::endl;
    for (auto e: g.edges())
        std::cout << e.first << ' ' << e.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Good question. I don't know of an easy way.

Comment: `bool operator!=(const EdgeIter& other) { return u_ != other.u_; }`? Shouldn't two `EdgeIter` be considered unequal when they actually point to different *edges*?

Comment: I assume you want the iterator to be lazy; filling a `vector` with the results and then iterating that wouldn't be acceptable, right?

Comment: You didn't account isolated nodes, `cbegin()` will return `cend()` in that case.

Comment: 2 days running, 3 answers, yet no comment, upvote/downvote or accept from you. Is there anything wrong with any of the answers? If so,  please indicate how to improve, and I'll edit or retract.

Comment: @Zeta: The `operator !=` is indeed broken, it was only intended as a quick hack to allow comparing against `end()`...

Comment: @svick: Actually, that idea is not so bad. But yeah, it might be that only an edge with a certain property is sought and the user would `break` out early.

Comment: @Zeta: I tried to account for isolated nodes, which is part why the code is so complicated. In the example, 0 and 4 are isolated. Can you elaborate on where you see the problem?

Answer (score 15):

I strongly recommend using the [**Boost.Graph**](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/) library for such computations. The main reason is that **graphs are complicated data structures** on which you can run even more **complicated algorithms**. Even if your own hand-made data structure works correctly, it is likely not to run efficiently (in terms of space/time complexity) and may not support the algorithms that your applications needs.

As an indication on how accessible this library is: I had no prior experience with Boost.Graph, but it took about 30 minutes to come up with the following 30 lines of code that completely reproduces your example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

typedef unsigned V;
typedef std::pair<V, V> E;

// store neighbors in a std::set, vertices in a std::vector
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS> Graph;

int main()
{
   // construct the graph
   E e[] = { E(1,2), E(2,3), E(1,3) };
   Graph g(std::begin(e), std::end(e), 5);

   std::cout << "iterate over vertices, then over its neighbors\n";
   auto vs = boost::vertices(g);
   for (auto vit = vs.first; vit != vs.second; ++vit) {
       auto neighbors = boost::adjacent_vertices(*vit, g);
       for (auto nit = neighbors.first; nit != neighbors.second; ++nit)
           std::cout << *vit << ' ' << *nit << std::endl;
   }

   std::cout << "iterate directly over edges\n";
   auto es = boost::edges(g);
   for (auto eit = es.first; eit != es.second; ++eit) {
       std::cout << boost::source(*eit, g) << ' ' << boost::target(*eit, g) << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Output on [LiveWorksSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4rLZzZ$12)

Granted, because `boost::edges` returns a `std::pair`, you [can't use range-based for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167598/why-was-pair-range-access-removed-from-c11) on the edges, but that's only syntactic sugar which you can try to repair by defining your own begin/end functions. What's important is that you can iterate over edges directly.

Note that the `boost_adjacency_list` data structure provides you with edge and vertex operations of [**well-defined time and space complexity**](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html). The code above merely reproduces your example without knowing what kind of operations you really want. Changing the underlying containers allows you to make tradeoffs appropriately to your application.

Comment: I've looked into boost graph before. While it is OK (but not great) if you just want to use graph algorithms, I found it extremely hard to code new algorithms. See for example [heir implementation of Dijkstra's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp) (a very simple algorithm), it seems completely opaque to me. Anyway, my main interest was in how to implement the iterator, ideally with the range-based for. I'll look into how it is done in boost.

Comment: Using C++11 you can use things like `for( auto e : boost::edges(g) )` if you first implement `std::begin(const std::pair<T,T>& eItPair)` to return `eItPair.first` and  `std::end(const std::pair<T,T>& eItPair)` to return `eItPair.second`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your internal representation of a graph, `std::vector<std::unordered_set<Vertex>>`, is what makes the code hard to write/read. Maybe another representation (e.g. `std::set<std::pair<Vertex, Vertex>>`) would make your code simpler. However, it's hard to tell since we don't know exactly what are the requirements of `Graph`.

Anyway, as pointed out by **Zeta** there's a bug in `EdgeIter::operator !=()`. For instance, the code below:

```
int main() {

    Graph g(5);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);

    auto i1 = g.edges().begin();
    auto i2 = i1;
    ++i2;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << (i1 != i2) << std::endl;
}
```

outputs `false`. Hence, the code considers that `i1` and `i2` are not different when they clearly are.

**Update:**

It's probably obvious but here is a simpler version which uses a different representation for the graph. However, I emphasize that **this may not be satisfactory** depending on your requirements for `Graph` (which I don know):

```
#include <set>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned Vertex;

class Graph {

public:

    typedef std::pair<Vertex, Vertex> Edge;
    typedef std::set<Edge> Edges;

    void addEdge(Vertex u, Vertex v) {
      edges_.insert({u, v});
    }

    const Edges& edges() { return edges_; }

private:

    Edges edges_;
};

int main() {

    Graph g;

    g.addEdge(1, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.addEdge(1, 3);    

    for (auto e: g.edges())
        std::cout << e.first << ' ' << e.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting alternative. However, I often need to iterate over all neighbors of a vertex. It's not obvious how to do that here. Note also you'd need to normalize the edge to u < v before inserting, since I want {u, v} and {v, u} to be the same

Answer (score 1):

An opportunity for a shameless plug! I have a project [**linq-cpp**](https://github.com/timothy-shields/linq-cpp) for bringing .NET LINQ functionality to C++11, and this is a perfect example for where it really shines.

Using it, you could write a function like the following:

```
TEnumerable<std::pair<int, int>> EnumerateEdges(std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>& neighbors)
{
    return Enumerable::FromRange(neighbors)
        .SelectManyIndexed([](std::unordered_set<int>& bNodes, int aNode)
        {
            return Enumerable::FromRange(bNodes)
                .Select([=](int bNode){ return std::make_pair(aNode, bNode); });
        });
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
EnumerateEdges(neighbors).ForEach([](std::pair<int, int> edge)
{
    /* your code */
});
```

Or maybe like this:

```
auto edges = EnumerateEdges(neighbors).ToVector();
```

Comment: This looks very nice. Can it be adapted to use the ranged-based for syntax somehow? Also, I don't see where the condition to only yield pairs with aNode < bNode is implemented, can that be added?

Comment: So while it could be adapted to a range-based for syntax, I have intentionally not done that.  That would be an iterator/enumerator; this is an enumerable.  The distinction is talked about in the readme.  To get only the edges with a < b, you could simply add a call to the `Where` function in the query.  The github readme talks about all this stuff.

Comment: Other operations like "do a BFS from node X" can similarly be written in an extremely simple and reusable fashion. You can then do stuff like `BFS(myNode).Where(/* some predicate on nodes */).Take(10)` to mean "get the 10 nodes closest to `myNode` that satisfy some predicate."