# Range based for with pair<Iterator,Iterator>

Tags: c++, for-loop, boost, iterator

I have a question with respect to the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15828866/2160256

As stated there, we cannot use range based for with BGL like this:

```
   for(auto e : boost::edges(g))
       // do something with e
```

However, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) it states, that we can overload the begin() and end() functions that are required to use range based for semantics. So I tried:

```
   template<class I>
   I begin(std::pair<I,I>& p)
   { return p.first;}

   template<class I>
   I end(std::pair<I,I>& p)
   { return p.second;}
```

However, the compiler still complains:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘`begin(std::pair<some_really_ugly_type,some_really_ugly_type>&)`’

What am I doing wrong? Does the name lookup not work? Or is this not possible after all?
I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167598/why-was-pair-range-access-removed-from-c11), which works, but shouldtn't it be possible with the begin/end free function overlods as well?
Regards, Marti

BTW: I find it really tiresome to write

```
   typename Graph::edge_iterator ebegin, eend;
   std::tie(ebegin,eend) = boost::edges(_graph);
   std::for_each(ebegin,eend,[&](const edge_descriptor& e){/*do something with e*/;});
```

UPDATE: C++17 should now allow the following :-)

```
auto [ebegin,eend] = boost::edges(_graph);
```

Comment: Think twice before doing this. There are good reasons not to make the assumption that any iterator pair is-a range. See my answer for my favourite idiom.

Comment: @sehe good reasons suggested adding type `range`, but standard did neither, they did not add range and they did not allow par of iterators to be used in for range loop. Good job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a range-based `for` loop, name lookup for non-member `begin()` and `end()` uses ADL only. It doesn't perform ordinary unqualified lookup. §6.5.4 [stmt.ranged]/p1.3:

> - if `_RangeT` is a class type, the *unqualified-id*s `begin` and `end` are looked up in the scope of class `_RangeT` as if by class member access
>     lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one
>     declaration, [...]
> - otherwise, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `begin(__range)` and
>     `end(__range)`, respectively, where `begin` and `end` are looked up in the
>     associated namespaces (3.4.2). [ *Note*: Ordinary unqualified lookup
>     (3.4.1) is not performed. —*end note* ]

Hence, your `begin()` and `end()` overloads are not found.

Answer (score 7):

Iterator pairs are **not** ranges by design! The idea was specifically rejected from the language and library specification. See e.g.

- paper [**n2995.pdf** Pairs do not make good ranges](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2995.pdf)

If you "find it tiresome" to write the `tie()` workaround, just use

```
for (auto& edge : make_iterator_range(boost::edges(_graph)))
    /*do something with edge*/;
```

You could alias `boost::make_iterator_range` something shorter, but my editor¹ suggests `make_iterator_range` as completion when I type `mir`. This is plenty speedy for me

---

¹ of course, that editor is Vim

Comment: Thanks, i do not have problems with verbose oneliners, but those three liners do hurt :-) I replaced my own make_range with calls to boost :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have free `begin()` and `end()` functions as per [T.C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27140852/2069064). However, what you can do, is just make your own class and add member `begin` and `end` to it:

```
template <typename I>
struct iter_pair : std::pair<I, I>
{ 
    using std::pair<I, I>::pair;

    I begin() { return this->first; }
    I end() { return this->second; }
};
```

And just use that instead of a normal `pair`:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

iter_pair<decltype(v.begin())> pr{v.begin(), v.end()};

for (int i : pr) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would expand on Barry's answer and suggest (until C++17) to add

```
template <typename I>
iter_pair<I> make_range(std::pair<I, I> p) {
    return iter_pair<I>(p);
}
```

to be used as

```
for (auto e : make_range(boost::edges(g)))
    // do something with e
```

Comment: The reason I suggest a helper function is to allow it to deduce the template type instead of declaring it explicitly:  
  
`for (auto e : make_range(boost::edges(g)))`
  
instead of  
  
`for (auto e : iter_pair<?>(boost::edges(g)))`  
  
where you have to guess the correct type for `<?>` .  
  
C++17 should introduce [class_template_deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction) in constructor calls, alleviating the need for the helper function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Boost FOREACH macro uses C++03 declarations and explicit template code, it ought to work with conventional lookup rules instead of special `for` rules.

You might make sure that it expands the old way even though range-based `for` is available.

Another approach would be to make your own class that is derived from the pair, but contains the `begin` and `end` members.  Then write

```
for (e: mypair(p))
```

Instead of

```
for (e: p)
```