# Is it possible to use range-based for loops with iterator ranges?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Consider the usage with `std::multimap`, where I am given a range of iterators:

```
std::unordered_multimap<std::string, MyObject> mymap;

auto& range = mymap.equal_range("some_key");
for (auto& the_pair : range)
{
}
```

Now, the code above does not compile, but I am using it for demonstration purposes. Is it possible to use range-based for loops with a pair of iterators like this? I don't imagine it is possible directly, so I guess my question is really about whether or not there is an adapter class in STL for this use case. I could probably write my own but this seems like a common case.

## Update:

If this is not a common case and STL does not provide such a proxy or adapter for this type of usage, what is required to implement them? I was thinking that I'd need to overload the free functions `begin` and `end` and also define an adapter iterator class for `std::pair<T,U>`. I'm just taking a conceptual stab at it, but please let me know! Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, range-based for calls `std::begin` and `std::end`. There isn't any overloads for `std::pair`. At one point, this [feature existed in a draft standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167598/why-was-pair-range-access-removed-from-c11) but was removed. You can write your own code. Stealing from sellibitze:

```
template<class Iter>
struct iter_pair_range : std::pair<Iter,Iter> {
    iter_pair_range(std::pair<Iter,Iter> const& x)
    : std::pair<Iter,Iter>(x)
    {}
    Iter begin() const {return this->first;}
    Iter end()   const {return this->second;}
};

template<class Iter>
inline iter_pair_range<Iter> as_range(std::pair<Iter,Iter> const& x)
{ return iter_pair_range<Iter>(x); }

int main() {
    std::unordered_multimap<std::string, MyObject> mymap;

    auto range = mymap.equal_range("some_key");
    for (auto& the_pair : as_range(range))
    {
    }
}
```

You can look at [n2995](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2995.pdf) from 2009 which talks about adding ranged support to the standard library. Maybe you're better off using [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Your `iter_pair_range` class is assuming both types in the pair are the same type which is not the case in my example.

Comment: @void.pointer what do you mean? Equal_range will always return a pair of the same type

Comment: @void.pointer The types in the pair are not the same, but the iterator-type is. It's a `multimap<std::string, MyObject>::const_iterator` on both occasions. In fact, a range-based for won't even work with `begin()` and `end()` returning different kinds of iterators.

Comment: My apologies, I was looking at the wrong `pair` object!

Comment: Why was this removed from the standard?  Anyone know?

Comment: @Robinson Maybe because the proposal was written in MS Word. And to make it even worse: using the default color-theme ;-)

Comment: @Robinson He provided a link near the top of his answer that might help answer your question.

Comment: Thanks I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

The template-based answer is probably what you are looking for, but i would use a [for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) instead with a lambda. It is cleaner and easier to digest.

Comment: I ended up using your recommendation, I didn't even consider `std::for_each`. It is much simpler. However, my question specifically asks for a solution in terms of range based for so I'm going to accept the answer with that in mind. Thanks for your reminder!

Answer (score 1):

With C++ 20 you can use [std::ranges::subrange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange).

```
std::unordered_multimap<std::string, MyObject> mymap;

auto range = mymap.equal_range("some_key");
for (auto & [key, value] : std::ranges::subrange(range.first, range.second))
{
}
```