# std::multimap equal _range and C++20 std::views::values do not work nicely together

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have the following code, it works, but C++20 version does not look much better than C++17 version. My guess issue is that `multimap` `equal_range` returns a `pair` and ranges can not figure out that is a pair of valid iterators.

Is there a way to write this in a shorter nicer way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    std::multimap<bool,int> oddness{{false,2}, {true,3}, {true,47}, {false,74656}};
    // nice, does not work:
    // oddness.equal_range(true) | std::views::values;
    // works:
    oddness | std::views::values;

    // working code:
    auto odds = oddness.equal_range(true);
    const auto odds_view = std::views::values(std::ranges::subrange(odds.first, odds.second));
    for (const auto& odd : odds_view) {
        std::cout << odd << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `equal_range` returns a `pair<It, It>`, which is (unfortunately) not itself a range. This is one of the more unfortunate legacy API decisions in my opinion - since we have this excellent name but it does something... less than great.

You used to be able to take a `pair<It, It>` and easily convert it to a `subrange`, but that's not necessarily valid and was removed (first in [LWG3281](https://wg21.link/lwg3281) and then the rest in [LWG3404](https://wg21.link/lwg3404)). Not all pairs of iterators are actually ranges (several algorithms return two iterators that are not - like `minmax_element` or `mismatch`).

But that's okay, we can just write our own explicit one:

```cpp
struct pair_to_range_t {
    template <typename I>
    friend constexpr auto operator|(std::pair<I, I> const& pr, pair_to_range_t) {
        return std::ranges::subrange(pr.first, pr.second);
    }
};

inline constexpr pair_to_range_t pair_to_range{};
```

And then you can write:

```cpp
oddness.equal_range(true) | pair_to_range | std::views::values;
```

Comment: shame it got removed, but it is safer, I remember that range based for loop had similar standardization change https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167598/why-was-pair-range-access-removed-from-c11?rq=1