# odd behavior of c++ namespace

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces

here is some code, that displays the oddity:

```
namespace ns
{
  typedef int int_type;

  class classus {
    public: 
      int a = 0;
  };

  void print(classus c){
    printf("a equals %i \n", c.a);
  }
  void print(int_type a){
    printf("a equals %i \n", a);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ns::int_type a1 = 2;
  ns::classus a2;
  ns::print(a1); // this line wont work without explicit ns:: scope
  print(a2); // this line works with or without explicit ns:: scope
}
```

This builds and runs on visual studio 2017. Intellisense is also perfectly happy with it.

It seems variables of class contained in a namespace, pollutes the entire line with that namespace scope. Is this a bug or a feature? Either way, is there some documentation about this... have not found any

Comment: This also demonstrates the easiest way to disable ADL: use a typedef to import the type from a namespace that doesn't have any functions. https://godbolt.org/z/PmmgZs

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash, thanks. Immediately when i saw your example I wanted to get rid of "using". How about this : https://godbolt.org/z/fT7gVf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The feature that is confusing you is called ADL (argument dependent lookup)

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl):

> Argument-dependent lookup, also known as ADL, or Koenig lookup, is the set of rules for looking up the unqualified function names in function-call expressions, including implicit function calls to overloaded operators. These function names are looked up in the namespaces of their arguments in addition to the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup.
>
> Argument-dependent lookup makes it possible to use operators defined in a different namespace.

In your example `a2` being from the namespace `ns` is enough for the compiler to also consider `ns` when looking for `print`.

The interesting part of your example is that `int_type` is also coming from `ns`, though it is just a typedef and `int` is not declared in `ns`. Consider that a typedef does not introduce a new type (rather an alias). So `a2` really is an `int`.

**PS**: This is not specific to Visual studio. Any compiler conforming to the standard should accept the code posted.

Comment: But why not `a1`?

Comment: @acraig5075 good question. Seems like ADL is not triggered for typedefs. `a1` is just an `int`

Comment: Yes, ADL is based on the types of the arguments. `ns::int_type a1;` is entirely equivalent to `int a1;` and the type `int` has no "associated namespaces".

Comment: This seems right... all though I cant say I am happy with this design choice. Could you please add to the answer that this is (or could and should) be featured on other compilers/systems

Comment: @StefanKarlsson You may find some rationale in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205188/580083).

Comment: @StefanKarlsson what do you mean with "Could you please add to the answer that this is (or could and should) be featured on other compilers/systems" ? ADL is part of the C++ standard, every compliant compiler has to implement it

Comment: @StefanKarlsson concerning the "I cant say I am happy with this design choice" - I cannot imagine how operator overloads would be pratical without ADL, though elsewhere ADL is mainly a source of confusion

Comment: @StefanKarlsson ah you mean the rationale for typedefs not triggering ADL? COnsider that the type of `a1` really is `int` and there could be many different typedefs for `int` in completely unrelated namespaces

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, regarding this being valid for other compilers, this is given from your link and from what you said in comments: ADL is part of the c++ standard. I think adding that in an edit would make the answer even better. My question is tagged with visual-c++, and visual studio is mentioned explicitly. I have verified same behavior with gcc, as expected. So good answer, I learned something, lets make the answer great.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, regarding design choice, it probably is by necessity. In this particular instance (for the code posted) it provides no benefits... Your argument of typdef being alias makes perfect sense.

Comment: @StefanKarlsson compiler specifics are kinda rare, I prefer to focus on c++ and only if it is compiler specific I would mention it. Anyhow, if you feel it is missing in the answer, feel free to edit it