# How to pretty print GLM math library object values when using Google Test

Tags: c++, googletest, glm-math

I am trying to test some math operations with GLM using GoogleTest and pretty print when the assertions fail. I have been following the guides regarding the pretty printing and I found a function named `PrintTo`. Overloading this function for a custom structure in a namespace works:

```cpp
namespace my_ns {
struct A {
  A(uint32_t a_, uint32_t b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {}

  uint32_t a = 0, b = 0;

  bool operator==(const A &rhs) const { return a == rhs.a && b == rhs.b; }
};
void PrintTo(const test::A &value, std::ostream *out) {
  *out << value.a << " - " << value.b;
}

}

TEST(PrettyTest, Test) { EXPECT_EQ(my_ns::A(10, 20), my_ns::A(20, 25)); }
```

This works and I get human readable expect failure messages:

```
error: Expected equality of these values:
  my_ns::A(10, 20)
    Which is: 10 - 20
  my_ns::A(20, 25)
    Which is: 20 - 25
```

However, when I am trying to do the same for GLM math library, I keep getting the default string, which is a binary value:

```cpp
namespace glm {

void PrintTo(const vec3 &value, std::ostream *out) {
  *out << to_string(value);
}

} // namespace glm

TEST_F(PrettyTest, GlmTest) { EXPECT_EQ(glm::vec3(1.0f), glm::vec3(2.0f)); }
```

The following test prints:

```
 error: Expected equality of these values:
  glm::vec3(1.0f)
    Which is: 12-byte object <00-00 80-3F 00-00 80-3F 00-00 80-3F>
  glm::vec3(2.0f)
    Which is: 12-byte object <00-00 00-40 00-00 00-40 00-00 00-40>
```

This issue only exists in GLM and I cannot figure out what causes this issue. I tried to use different namespaces but I could not get it to working.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from glm source code [here](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/ext/vector_float3.hpp), `vec3` is not a type, but a typedef in namespace `glm` to the actual type, which for some versions of the library resides in the same `glm` namespace (see [here](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec3.hpp)), but for other (older) - in `glm::detail` namespace (see [here](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00131_source.html)). Note that ADL doesn't add namespaces of typedefs to associated namespaces, only namespaces of actual type definitions, which is discussed in
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155450/adl-with-typedefs-from-another-namespace). So, since in your case ADL doesn't help to find `PrintTo` function in `glm` namespace, for your version of glm it most probably will do its job if you put function definition into `glm::detail` namespace like this:

```
namespace glm::detail {
    void PrintTo(const ::glm::vec3 &value, std::ostream *out) {
        *out << ::glm::to_string(value);
    }
} // namespace glm::detail
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! However, unfortunately the code that you provided does not work. I am using the latest version of GLM and it uses the default `glm` namespace for vec3 (not for vec4 though for some reason...). I tried both `glm` and `glm::detail` one and even added btoh but nothing seems to be working here.

Comment: I found out that there is an I/O extension for GLM and I included that. I can now print directly to the stream `std::cout << glm::vec3(2.0f)` but the same thing does not work with googletest, which supports I/O overrides.

Comment: @Gasim Hmm, very strange. About vec4, in the (modern) repository I provided situation for vec4 seems the same as for vec3 (both typedef and type within glm namespace).

Comment: After lots of searching and trying to understand the issue, I found out what the problem was. I had the case of ODR where only one test file had the changes that were described in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had many test files but the customization that I was applying was only in one file. I debugged this by removing all the tests and keeping only one. As I did that, everything worked. When I added a new test file as compile target, the printing stopped working. I solved this issue by creating a custom header file and adding encapsulating all the logic in that file and including only that file in my tests:

```cpp
// Testing.h
#pragma once

namespace glm {

// Covers all vectors
template <length_t L, typename T, qualifier Q>
void PrintTo(const vec<L, T, Q> &value, std::ostream *out) {
  *out << to_string(value);
}

// Covers all matrices
template <length_t C, length_t R, typename T, qualifier Q>
void PrintTo(const mat<C, R, T, Q> &value, std::ostream *out) {
  *out << to_string(value);
}

// Covers all quaternions
template <typename T, qualifier Q>
void PrintTo(const qua<T, Q> &value, std::ostream *out) {
  *out << to_string(value);
}

} // namespace glm

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

// ------
// In all my test files

// other includes...
#include "Testing.h"

// test code here
```

Comment: So summarizing the info in your self-answer - `PrintTo` was not declared before its usage?

Comment: No, it was declared in one file but not in another one, which caused issues. Here is a wikipedia link explaining this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule. I basically made sure that all my files have the same function declarations.